# Problem using IRremote library

Tags: ir, wireless, arduino-pro-micro

I am using arduino pro micro 5v 16Mhz. I have built a simple IR transmitter circuit as shown. [image: Led is connected to pin 9 through 330ohm resistor]

The code i am using is 
https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/examples/IRsendDemo/IRsendDemo.ino

Although this worked yesterday, it doesn't seem to work now. I was able to turn on and off my TV yesterday but the led is not even blinking now. I checked led, its working.

After hours of trying to make it work I tried different library. 
https://github.com/cyborg5/IRLib2/blob/master/IRLib2/examples/send/send.ino

Surprisingly this seems to work but the code is a bit complicated for receiver.

I want to use the first library. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what help anyone can give you here. You had it working, presumably changed nothing, and now it doesn't -- how can we debug that?

Comment: It seems the library got the timer pins wrong I changed them and its working now.

Comment: How did it ever work?

Comment: I used nrf24l01 module in between and maybe it changed timer settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with timer timer settings in library. I checked different timer configurations with different pins and its working now. I found out that timer4 uses pin 13 which is not used in Pro Micro board so I am now using timer 3.